# Removing sprite from layer not removing rect with it (Cocos2d)?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, sprite

I am making a game in Cocos2d. Everything is okay, so far. I used [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) tutorial to get collision detection to work. It works, but whenever an 'enemy' spawns where a bullet was deleted (because the bullet that was deleted hit a target, therefore, was deleted), the enemy is automatically deleted, too. I think it's because it doesn't remove the rect that was declared for the sprite. Note, it also can go through more than one enemy, even though the bullet is deleted. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:
I found out what the problem was. I had the shoot method set in a schedule:@selector method, with no set interval. That meant that it would fire bullets 60fps fast. So I was getting TWO bullets with ONE click. They were so close together, that it took me a while to notice it. I won't make that mistake again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the following code? (from [How To Make A Simple iPhone Game with Cocos2D Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial))

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {

  NSMutableArray *projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (CCSprite *projectile in _projectiles) {
    CGRect projectileRect = CGRectMake(
      projectile.position.x - (projectile.contentSize.width/2), 
      projectile.position.y - (projectile.contentSize.height/2), 
      projectile.contentSize.width, 
      projectile.contentSize.height);

    NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (CCSprite *target in _targets) {
      CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
        target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2), 
        target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2), 
        target.contentSize.width, 
        target.contentSize.height);

      if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectileRect, targetRect)) {
        [targetsToDelete addObject:target];             
      }                     
    }

    for (CCSprite *target in targetsToDelete) {
      [_targets removeObject:target];
      [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];                                    
    }

    if (targetsToDelete.count > 0) {
      [projectilesToDelete addObject:projectile];
    }
    [targetsToDelete release];
  }

  for (CCSprite *projectile in projectilesToDelete) {
    [_projectiles removeObject:projectile];
    [self removeChild:projectile cleanup:YES];
  }
  [projectilesToDelete release];
}
```

> whenever an 'enemy' spawns where a bullet was deleted, the enemy is automatically deleted, too.

It sounds that the bullet is removed from the layer, but it is not removed from _projectiles array.

```
    [_projectiles removeObject:projectile];
```

Are you sure that this code works?

Answer (score 0):

Rect is not a seperate entity from your bullet. Rect is the property associated with the bullet. As soon as your "bullet is deleted" the rect will no longer be valid.

What you should be looking at is your collision checking code.

You probably want to surround your bullet collision check code with a condition like:

```
if(bullet exists)
{
    check for collision
}
```

Since you haven't posted code I could only post pseudo code here. Maybe if you post your collision checking code I could show you in more detail.

Comment: dharth Iyer @Siddharth lyer (i can't tell if that's a 'I' or a 'l') I declare a rect separate from the sprite declaration.

Comment: Why not use the sprite's frame property?

Comment: dharth Iyer @Siddharth lyer I've tried using [bullet boundingBox] and [enemy boundingBox] and I get the same results